# How to tell Django collectstatic to use Amazon S3?

Tags: python, django, collectstatic

I have followed [this howto](https://www.caktusgroup.com/blog/2014/11/10/Using-Amazon-S3-to-store-your-Django-sites-static-and-media-files/) to setup django + S3. Specifically:

```
import os

# AWS credentials
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = os.environ['AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME']
AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN = '%s.s3.amazonaws.com' % AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME
# boto config
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = os.environ['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID']
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = os.environ['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']
AWS_HEADERS = {  # see http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#expires
    'Expires': 'Thu, 31 Dec 2099 20:00:00 GMT',
    'Cache-Control': 'max-age=94608000',
}

# For the static files
STATICFILES_LOCATION = 'static'
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'myapp.custom_storages.StaticStorage'
STATIC_URL = 'https://%s/%s/' % (AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN, STATICFILES_LOCATION)

# For the media files
MEDIAFILES_LOCATION = 'media'
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'myapp.custom_storages.MediaStorage'
MEDIA_URL = 'https://%s/%s/' % (AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN, MEDIAFILES_LOCATION)
```

My custom storages are simple `S3BotoStorage`s:

```
from django.conf import settings
from storages.backends.s3boto import S3BotoStorage


class StaticStorage(S3BotoStorage):
    location = settings.STATICFILES_LOCATION


class MediaStorage(S3BotoStorage):
    location = settings.MEDIAFILES_LOCATION
```

I would expect that `collectstatic` would honor this configuration (as explained in the howto), and use the `myapp.custom_storages.StaticStorage` to upload collected static files to S3. Instead, it just uses the local filesystem. Since I have:

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'mycollectstatic')
```

(just because having `'static'` there seems too confusing to me), I can clearly see that:

```
» python manage.py collectstatic

You have requested to collect static files at the destination
location as specified in your settings:

    /absolute-path/mycollectstatic

This will overwrite existing files!
Are you sure you want to do this?

Type 'yes' to continue, or 'no' to cancel:
```

So it seems that `collectstatic` command is using `STATIC_ROOT` even when `STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'myapp.custom_storages.StaticStorage'`. Is this expected?

Should I configure `STATIC_ROOT` differently when using another `STATICFILES_STORAGE`? Where is this documented?

Comment: what's your python version and which packages do yo use?

Comment: @LouisBarranqueiro: python 2.7.6, `Django==1.8.5`, no special packages for this.

Comment: Did you try `DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'myapp.custom_storages.StaticStorage'` ? Concerning, `STATIC_ROOT` attribute, you don't have to edit tit. It works fine for me with.