# Change FileField to CharField or change file location to S3

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models

I currently have my files saved in my own server using FileField. And I want to make a migration for saving my files in S3. I was thinking in replace the FileField to a CharField keeping the file names and then, add the domain before it, to keep the track of the files. And then I'd migrate to S3.

Is there a simpler way to make this in Django? Is it even possible to change a FileField to a CharField and keep the files path as a string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey I was succesful in leaving the FileFields as is and using django-storages. Then using the storage injected into the file field to make it use s3.
I did not have to migrate the database for this.
https://django-storages.readthedocs.io/en/latest/backends/amazon-S3.html

Comment: Looks pretty good to me. I'll give it a try

Comment: We have out files into `media` folder. Do you know how to make something similar to the collectstatic for uploading the actual files in server to S3?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33774921/how-to-tell-django-collectstatic-to-use-amazon-s3